# How can I take binary representation of float-pointing types?

Tags: c++, floating-point

How can I take binary representation of float-pointing types? Or how can I take mantissa and exponent of float-pointing number?

Comment: What did you try, what didn't work? Please show us you've done some research.

Comment: If you don't need to do it programmatically then one of the tools I [mention here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22567773/1708801) may be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at `frexp` function to get significand and exponent: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/frexp/

Comment: +1 it's what i intended to answer, but the internet connection died. happily new equipment (parabola for sattelite internets) has arrived at the post office. still, very frustrating.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf - I know your pain :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the best way and probably depends on the compiler, but you can create a union of appropriately sized unsigned integer and the floating-point type. Assign the float, and read the int.

Answer (score 2):

you can use unions

```
union converter
{
  float number;
  struct
  {
    unsigned int mantisa  : 23;
    unsigned int exponent : 8;
    unsigned int sign     : 1;
  } binary;
};
```

With this structure you can extract mantisa, exponent and sign data easily:

```
union converter convert;

convert.number = 24.6;
int mantisa = convert.binary.mantisa;
int exponent = convert.binary.exponent;
int sign = convert.binary.sign;
```

Comment: I think this will not work on *Big-Endian* architectures, such as Power-PC, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    float test{ 9.9f };
    unsigned char *print{ (unsigned char *)&test };
    unsigned int mask{ 1 };
    for (int i = sizeof(float) - 1; i >= 0; --i){
        unsigned int temp{ print[i] };
        for (int i = 7; i >= 0; --i)
            cout << ((temp & (mask << i)) >> i);
    }
cout << endl;
return 0;
}
```

for double type just substitudes those two floats in code.

please note that this code only work for little-endian machine  and the output i got is
01000001000111100110011001100110

Answer (score 1):

**Little-Endian:**

```
void func(float f)
{
    char  arr[sizeof(f)];
    char* ptr = (char*)&f;
    for (int i=0; i<sizeof(f); i++)
        arr[i] = ptr[i];
    // Now use 'arr' as you will...
}
```

**Big-Endian:**

```
void func(float f)
{
    char  arr[sizeof(f)];
    char* ptr = (char*)&f;
    for (int i=0; i<sizeof(f); i++)
        arr[i] = ptr[sizeof(f)-1-i];
    // Now use 'arr' as you will...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to obtain the binary representation of a floating point type then using a union and [std::bitset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) seems the quickest way to go.

In *C* we know type punning though a union is ok(*[see my footnote here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20956250/1708801)*) but in *C++* it is a not clear so it would be better to go with a compiler that explicitly supports it such as [gcc which documents this support in C++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Type-punning).

A quick implementation would be as follows (*[see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d86d601380d07792)*):

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

union floatToInt
{
   float f ;
   unsigned int u ;
} ;

int main()
{
    floatToInt u1 ;

    u1.f = 3.4f ;

    std::bitset<32> bs1( u1.u ) ;

    std::cout << bs1 << std::endl ;
}
```

with the following result:

> 01000000010110011001100110011010

which if we plug this into [IEEE 754 Converter](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html), gives us back `3.4`.