# perl6 - Converting data in a Blob into a Num

Tags: raku, representation

I've got some bytes in a [blob, an immutable buffer for binary data](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Blob) and I am looking for a way to convert what it holds into a [floating point data structure, `Num`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Num), since it is the class that fits all those 3 formats that could be in the $blob

1. IEEE Float
2. IEEE Double
3. IEEE Long Double

What would be the best way of doing that conversion?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Import `NativeCall`, perform a cast to a pointer of desired type and dereference the result:

```
use NativeCall;
nativecast(Pointer[num32], $blob).deref;
```

Comment: It seems that there is not type for the IEEE Long Double? I coudn't find a num128